# Extract a fields data from a Map<Integer, Object> into a String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an Customer Object like below.

```
public class Custoemr {
    private String Id;
    Private String Name;
    Private String Address;
    Private String Description;

    Setter/Getter;
    toString;
}
```

This is Contained in `Map<String, Customer> map`, which contains the customerId and Object as key and value respectively. For analysis purposes, I need to collect all the customer description data in String to be written in a file.

To do that I need to Extract data from description in String and not `List<String>`.

I saw several examples on the internet which collects them as a `List<String>` but I need it in a single String.
Is there a way to extract the information without iterating I mean by using java Streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
yourMap.values()
       .stream()
       .map(Customer::getDescription)
       .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Yeh That's What I wanted
Thanks @Eugene